# node.js / get request & define root folder in http module

Tags: node.js

I define the next http request:

```
var http = require("http");
http.get("http://localhost:8001/pro.html", function(respond) {
    check();}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got err: " + e.message);
});
```

Now, In the server side I define the next:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
// Some code
socket.on('data', function(d) {
var t = http.request(d, function (res){
            console.log(d);
            console.log(res.statusCode);
        });
// Some code}
```

I have two problems:

1. Nothing is printed. Why it doesn't get to  `console.log(d);console.log(res.statusCode);`?
2. Pro.html is located in `c://myFolder`. How I tell to my server the location of this page?

Thank you.

Comment: what is d ,it is not defined in your code ?

Comment: @mpm: Sorry, I correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the low-level socket module ('**net**') to implement an HTTP server.  The correct module is '**http**' ([Node.js HTTP documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)), and the implementation is simple:

Your client side:

```
var http = require("http");

http.get("http://localhost:8001/pro.html", function(response)
{
    response.setEncoding("utf8");
    response.on("data", function(data)
    {
        console.log("response:", data);
    });

}).on("error", function(e)
{
    console.log("Got err: " + e.message);
});
```

And for the server side:

```
var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    response.end("Here's your pro page!\n")

}).listen(8001);
```

Note that the above features an impractically-simple server that returns a fixed response without any regard to what URL is requested.  In any real application you would use some logic to map requested URLs to callback functions (to generate dynamic content), a static file server, an all-encompassing framework (like '**express**') or a combination of the above.